# docvars() produces an error after update to R version 4.3.0

Tags: r, quanteda

I’m using a script to do textual analysis and classification for quite a long time.

After updating my computer to R version 4.3.0, a line with docvars() produces an error. Until now, it was working perfectly. I’m using Quanteda 3.3.0.

The code:

```
docvars(my_corpus)
```

The error:

```
Error in UseMethod("docvars") : 
  no applicable method for 'docvars' applied to an object of class "c('corpus', 'character')"
```

As this code always worked and as I didn’t change anything into it, I wonder if it is the update to R version 4.3.0 that brought this problem.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried downgrading R and see if it works on the previous version? The package asks for R >= 3.5.0, so technically, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I downgraded to R version 4.2.3 Patched (2023-03-29 r84137) and the error doesn’t appear anymore. One more comment: the error seems related to a conflict between `Quanteda` and `readtext` libraries because if I don’t load `readtext`, then the problem disappears.

Comment: This ought to be an issue on the GitHub repo, with reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KenBenoit, I submitted an issue on the GitHub repo.